# Yii2 подключение сторонней библиотеки

Tags: php, yii2

Я недавно начал изучать Yii2 и столкнулся с такой задачей:

Есть библиотека PhpWord, мне нужно её подключить, я делаю так в коде приложения

```
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader;
```

Соответственно библиотека лежит в корне приложения в PhpOffice\PhpWord

Пространства имен класса вроде как совпадают, но почему-то класс не загружается PhpWord.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: композер-то о ней знает?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Установите класс через composer, тем более есть инструкция как это сделать: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: А на чем оно может быть основано?) На знаниях и опыте я так полагаю) В проекте Yii2 даже сам фреймворк подключается через composer. И все дополнительные библиотеки тем более. Это самый верный путь - классы будут автоматически подгружаться в случае надобности, и не надо никаких use.

Comment: Я установил библиотеку через composer, но когда я пытаюсь создать экземпляр класса, то все равно пишет, что такой класс не найден. Нужно ещё как-то путь до класса прописывать?

Comment: Какую ошибку выводит и как вы подключаете класс?

Comment: подключаю use PhpOffice\PhpWord и потом $word = new PhpWord();

Comment: Посмотрите по ссылке выше пункт "Getting started", возможно, вы что-то упустили во время подключения.

Answer (score 7):

Как вам и посоветовали проще всего подключить библиотеку через composer (думаю что он у вас еже установлен, но на всякий случай - https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md), в консоле, перейдите в корень и введите строку

`composer require "phpoffice/phpword":"dev-master"`

Но бывают случаи когда не можете или не хотите использовать composer, вы можите подключать свои расширения через конфигурацию - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-application.html#$extensions-detail

То есть вам нужно указать данные вашего расширения в конфигурации (к примеру \config\web.php) в ключе extensions.

```
...
'components'=>[...],
'params' => $params,
'extensions' => [
    'name' => 'extension name',
    'version' => 'version number',
    'bootstrap' => 'BootstrapClassName',
    'alias' => [
        '@alias1' => 'to/path1',
        '@alias2' => 'to/path2',
    ],
],
...
```

Тут нужно понимать что данная настройка заменяет основной файл фреймворка для расширений - `@vendor/yiisoft/extensions.php`, так что вы не сможете использовать composer и свои расширений одновременно. Но это можно обойти, для этого, в папке конфигураций, создайте новый файл (назовем его extensions.php) с кодом:

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

$extensionsDir = dirname(__DIR__). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'extensions';
$vendoExtension =  require_once  dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/yiisoft/extensions.php';

Yii::setAlias('@extensions', $extensionsDir);

$extensions = [
    'extension name'=>[
        'name' => 'extension name',
        'version' => 'version number',
        'bootstrap' => 'BootstrapClassName',  // optional, may also be a configuration array
        'alias' => [
            '@alias1' => 'to/path1',
            '@alias2' => 'to/path2',
        ],
    ]
];

foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
    if (isset($extension['alias'])) {
        foreach ($extension['alias'] as $alias => $path) {
            Yii::setAlias($alias, $path);
        }
    }
}

$merge = ArrayHelper::merge(
    $extensions,
    $vendoExtension
);

return $merge;
```

Обратите внимание что в массиве `$extensions` вы будите указывать свои расширения, по аналогии с файлом `@vendor/yiisoft/extensions.php`, посмотрите в нем как указываются расширения. Для текущего расширения настройка будет что то вроде этого:

```
'phpoffice/phpword'=>[
    'name'=>'phpoffice/phpword',
    'alias'=>[
        '@phpoffice/phpword'=>$extensionsDir . '/phpoffice/phpword',
    ],
]
```

(код не проверял)

Так же я использую отдельную папку для расширений которая установлены без composer (папка extensions в корне), путь к ней указана в переменной `$extensionsDir`, вы можете указать свою.

Остается изменить файл конфигурации (для примера web.php)

```
...
'extensions' => require_once 'extensions.php',
...
```

Далее заливайте свои расширения в папку указанную в `$extensionsDir` (в моем случае - extensions в корне), и подключайте их в массиве $extensions .

Все это использую в базовом шаблоне, в advanced шаблоне может что либо отличатся. Так же нужно понимать что многие расширения тянут за собой зависимые расширения, которые нужны им для работы, так что вам придется загрузить и подключить их все. Но удобно когда разрабатываешь свое расширение или расширяешь функционал для разового использования.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы использовать классы вы должны подключить их через `require`. Для того чтобы не делать это каждый раз был разработан [механизм автозагрузки](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.autoload.php). В случае с yii2 вы используете autoload от composer.

Вы можете [прописать алиас](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html#extension-aliases).

`Yii::setAlias('@PhpOffice', 'ProjectRoot/PhpOffice');`

Лучшим вариантом будет выделить `PhpOffice` как библиотеку и подключать её через composer как ответил @ShapeShifter08.

Comment: *либо установить в файле vendor\composer\autoload_psr4.php директорию array($baseDir . '/PhpOffice') для неймспейса PhpOffice.* - угадайте, через сколько секунд все сломается?

Comment: Я написал что до момента `composer update`. Не все программисты используют композер, некоторые по старинке загружают вручную. Это определенно плохо и я порекомендовал всё же выделить классы как библиотеку. Впрочем вы правы, нечего рекомендовать плохие практики. Я исправил ответ.

Comment: да в composer.json его прописать, если он вручную скачан